# selectOneMenu not Listing

Tags: java, primefaces, selectonemenu

Here is my problem. The following code does not list anything.  Can anyone help with this.  Code was taken right from primefaces website.

```
                    <p:outputLabel for="console" value="Basic:" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="console" value="" style="width:125px">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Xbox One" itemValue="Xbox One" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="PS4" itemValue="PS4" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Wii U" itemValue="Wii U" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error when you run your code? Might be you haven't added namespace in JSF page correctly. Please add some more detail of your issue.

Comment: Read [ask], [mcve] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Answer (score 1):

Hi have you added primefaces **namespace**(`xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"`) on top of the JSF page ?

Please see the example below:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" 
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
```